# Get files from Directory Argument, Sorting by Size

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes a command line argument, scans through the directory tree provided by the argument and creating a list of every file in the directory, and then sorting by length of files.

I'm not much of a script-guy - but this is what I've got and it's not working:

```
import sys
import os
from os.path import getsize

file_list = []

#Get dirpath
dirpath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
if os.path.isdir(dirpath):
    #Get all entries in the directory
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirpath):
        for name in files:
            file_list.append(name)
        file_list = sorted(file_list, key=getsize)
        for item in file_list:
            sys.stdout.write(str(file) + '\n')

else:
    print "not found"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest to read the help for the function [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). It seems to be the right choice for dealing with directory trees. If you look at the example for this function, you will see, you are on a good way...

Comment: I have to make sure: Do you want to sort files only of the provided directory or do you want to sort all files including the files in the subdirectory??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hopefully this function will help you out (I'm using Python 2.7):

```
import os    

def get_files_by_file_size(dirname, reverse=False):
    """ Return list of file paths in directory sorted by file size """

    # Get list of files
    filepaths = []
    for basename in os.listdir(dirname):
        filename = os.path.join(dirname, basename)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filepaths.append(filename)

    # Re-populate list with filename, size tuples
    for i in xrange(len(filepaths)):
        filepaths[i] = (filepaths[i], os.path.getsize(filepaths[i]))

    # Sort list by file size
    # If reverse=True sort from largest to smallest
    # If reverse=False sort from smallest to largest
    filepaths.sort(key=lambda filename: filename[1], reverse=reverse)

    # Re-populate list with just filenames
    for i in xrange(len(filepaths)):
        filepaths[i] = filepaths[i][0]

    return filepaths
```

Comment: I read this several times and I see it works, but I also noticed, that you have not discovered all the little things, that make your Python code more beautiful and readable. I hope you appreciate some advise:
Whenever you think you need to write `for i in range(len(some_list))`, use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead.
If you want to re-populate a list, drop your "array-way of thinking", try to use something like this instead: `lst = [ do_something(entry) for entry in lst ]`…

Comment: But if you generate a list, you want to repopulate without any further use, think about using generators. So you don't have to iterate over a list over and over again... saves memory, time…
If you are tired of reading this, watch this video… after years of programming in python I watched with my mouth wide opened!
[Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go)

Comment: `dirname` is a reserved name for a function in `os.path`, you should not use it as a variable name in your script. The function works great BTW!

Answer (score 22):

This is a approach using generators. Should be faster for large number of files…

This is the beginning of both examples:

```
import os, operator, sys
dirpath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
# make a generator for all file paths within dirpath
all_files = ( os.path.join(basedir, filename) for basedir, dirs, files in os.walk(dirpath) for filename in files   )
```

If you just want a list of the files without the size, you can use this:

```
sorted_files = sorted(all_files, key = os.path.getsize)
```

But if you want files and paths in a list, you can use this:

```
# make a generator for tuples of file path and size: ('/Path/to/the.file', 1024)
files_and_sizes = ( (path, os.path.getsize(path)) for path in all_files )
sorted_files_with_size = sorted( files_and_sizes, key = operator.itemgetter(1) )
```

Comment: Use `sorted_files_with_size.reverse()` to see largest files first. This is pretty fast and is useful to get a quick idea of which files are taking up space.

Comment: I haven't tested, but if a subdirectory contains other files and directories you don't have access to, most likely the sort is going to fail, because `os.path.getsize` would fail on those directories.

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting the command and not the first argument with `argv[0]`; use `argv[1]` for that:

```
dirpath = sys.argv[1]  # argv[0] contains the command itself.
```

For performance reasons I suggest you prefetch the file sizes instead of asking the OS about the size of the same file multiple times during the sorting (as suggested by Koffein, `os.walk` is the way to go):

```
files_list = []
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dirpath)):
    files_list.extend([(os.path.join(path, file), getsize(os.path.join(path, file))) for file in files])
```

Assuming you don't need the unsorted list, we will use the in-place sort() method:

```
files_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: the `files`-list is just a list of the file-names, isn't it? I think you have to join the `file`-names with `path`

Answer (score 2):

How about using pandas?

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

file_paths = [os.path.join(files_dir, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(files_dir)]
file_sizes = [os.path.getsize(file_path) for file_path in file_paths]

df = pd.DataFrame({'file_path': file_paths, 'file_size': file_sizes}).sort_values('file_size', ascending = False)
```

You can then easily recuperate the list of values from the `df`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import os,glob

for file in sorted(glob.glob("*.file extension"),key=lambda file:os.stat(file).st_size,reverse=True):
    print(f'{file} is {np.around(os.stat(file).st_size/(1024),decimals=1)} KB')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ...well ? Please do not leave all of us in suspense

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30131666)

Answer (score 0):

Plain old os.listdir but with extra params

```
import os
import operator

def oslistdir(directory='.', sort=True, size='smallest_first'):
    all_files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, file))]
    files_and_sizes = ((os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.getsize(os.path.join(directory, file))) for file in all_files)
    if sort:
        sorted_files_with_size = sorted(files_and_sizes, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=(size == 'largest_first'))
        sorted_files = [os.path.basename(file[0]) for file in sorted_files_with_size]
    else:
        sorted_files = [os.path.basename(file) for file in all_files]
    return sorted_files
```

#### Usage:

**Smallest first:**

`[f for f in oslistdir(my_folder_path, sort=True, size='smallest_first')]`

**Largest first:**

`[f for f in oslistdir(my_folder_path, sort=True, size='largest_first')]`