# Len() as argument for Dir()

Tags: excel, vba

So I am looping through a folder and have set a few arguments to filter the loop. I am trying to do so for file length as well but I am getting a run time error 13 type mismatch. Guessing there's no way to use file length as an argument for `Dir()`? What's a good workaround?

```
path = subF & "\"
extension = "*.xlsm"
partialName = "C*"
file = Dir(path & partialName & Len(file) = 13 & extension) '<- error
```

I can do

```
length = Len(file)
If length = 13 Then
```

inside the loop but without going into details, I need to do so outside of the loop.

Neither [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) or [this](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Dir-Function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e) is helping. And SO seems to only discuss file length with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252669/get-files-from-directory-argument-sorting-by-size) not excel :/

Comment: The only solution I can see is to use an If statement. You are effectively trying to do something only if something else occurs. Can you maybe explain why you cannot use an If statement and perhaps give more context (code) ?

Comment: Have you checked the VBE's Immediate window to see what `Debug.Print path & partialName & Len(file) = 13 & extension` returns? Looks to be something like `..\C*False*.xlsm`.

Comment: This will return a number to a string. That is your type mismatch.  Use str(len(file)) that will give you a string. But you still have issues here.  you will now have some number (such as 22 if that is the lenght) as a string C*22 = 13*.xlsm"

Comment: @Jeeped so `do while file = false`?

Comment: See edit to my comment.  Can you provide the string you think you should be getting?

Comment: Any .xlsm starting with "C"

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I have another loop that already set an upperbound that this loop needs to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want filenames that are a total of 13 characters long to include a period and a four letter file extension, so you really want filenames that are 8 characters long and starts with a C. The file mask you are currently using involved the asterisk which is the wildcard character for any number of characters. Switch to seven (7) question marks after the **C** and you should be filtering your [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) for file names that are eight characters long starting with a **C** with an `.xlsm` file extension.

```
path = subF & "\"
extension = ".xlsm"
partialName = "C???????"
file = Dir(path & partialName & extension) '\C???????.xlsm
```

Comment: Awwww this looks promising...brb Edit: how did it not work???? :/ It's giving me files that's much longer.

Comment: tbh, I cannot remember from my MS-DOS days whether that will show files with 4, 5 or 6 characters. Definitely something to test and rule in or out as the case may be. Just checked. It will show less than 8 characters but not more than 8 characters.

Comment: Did you leave the asterisk in at the start of the extension?

Comment: Looks like dir C????????????.xlsm will return files that start with C and are a total of 13 characters in the name not including the .extension That brings back memories. I had forgotten all about that.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped and Matt ^________^

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `*` wildcards and use the '?' wildcard instead:

```
path = subF & "\"
partialName = "C"
extension = ".xlsm"
file = Dir(path & partialName & String(7, "?") & extension)
```

If you want 13 char between "C" and ".xlsm" use `string(13, "?")` instead.

**Edit in response to comment:**

Minimizing variables -

```
path = subF & "\C" & String(7, "?") & ".xlsm"
file = Dir(path)
```

or

```
file = Dir(subF & "\C???????.xlsm")
```

Comment: Matt's idea is faster appending extension into partialName. Also eliminates ext variable.

Comment: Updated.  I had missed Matt's comment before posting my answer. I included the 'String(7, "?")'  to add some flexibility if needed.

Comment: Cool I like the effort.