# Simple Python List for new Unix user

Tags: python, unix

This may seem dumb, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to write a Python 2.6 function that takes a directory path and prints the size in bytes, of all the files, ignoring sub-directories.  I also want to reverse sort by size, like in this format:

fileA: 50000

fileB: 40000

fileC: 30000

File(s) - Total: 120000

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: You could use `os.listdir` , `os.path.isfile` and `os.path.getsize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

all_files = list()

dir_path = "." # replace with actual dir path

for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        all_files.append(tuple([file, os.path.getsize(path)]))

all_files.sort(key = lambda elm: elm[1])

for item in all_files:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253404/42346) slightly we can get a list of two-tuples with (filename, filesize).

```
import os

def get_files_by_file_size(dirname, reverse=False):
    """ Return list of two-tuples with file paths and file sizes 
        sorted by file size """

    # Get list of files
    filepaths = []
    for basename in os.listdir(dirname):
        filename = os.path.join(dirname, basename)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filepaths.append(filename)

    # Re-populate list with filename, size tuples
    for i in range(len(filepaths)):
        filepaths[i] = (filepaths[i], os.path.getsize(filepaths[i]))

    # Sort list by file size
    # If reverse=True sort from largest to smallest
    # If reverse=False sort from smallest to largest
    filepaths.sort(key=lambda filename: filename[1], reverse=reverse)

    return filepaths
```

And you'd call that like this:

```
dirname = os.getcwd()
get_files_by_file_size(dirname,reverse=True)
```

Comment: You're awesome, thanks a ton, and also for the clarifying comments!